# error in sum result- stop rounding

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sum that determines the difference of two numbers. In this case the two numbers (balance) is 454.27 and (current_bal) is 424.260000.

When using this function, it says bal_dif is 0.000000 when it should be 0.000001?

```
SUM(ISNULL(cast(balance-current_balance_amount as decimal)/100 ,2))AS bal_diff
```

I'm assuming its rounding, any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

[Set the precision of your `decimal` to `(9, 6)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), to preserve the value 6 places to the right of the decimal:

```
SUM(ISNULL(cast(balance-current_balance_amount as decimal(9,6))/100 ,2))AS bal_diff
```